How to align entire item in LaTeX?
I have right aligned the items as shown below in LaTeX. However, only the first line of each item is indented and the rest follows the original indent. How can I correct it for the entire item to be indented.
\begin{itemize}
\itemsep 2pt \leftmargin 5pt
\setlength{\itemindent}{20pt}
\item I have right aligned the items as shown below in Latex. However, only
the first line of each item is indented and the rest follows the
original indent. How can I correct it for the entire item to be
indented.
\end{itemize}



welcome! can you complete your code so we can reproduce the issue? does that really not give you an error? because the only way I can think it wouldn't error is if you've redefined itemize to not be a list or you aren't using latex, which is the only format overleaf supports, as far as I know.

\setlength{\itemindent}{0pt}

The first rule of markup languages: don't touch what's right by default.

Note that the version of the question I answered did not include \item in the code snippet. This was in the first version. It was removed by the OP in the second (which is the first I saw). It was then restored by somebody else in the fourth.
You've not provided usable code, but if I assume that you are

using LaTeX
using a standard class such as article
haven't redefined itemize to something which isn't a list (or redefined list to not be a list)
then the code you posted surely fails to compile without errors.

More specifically, I assume you get something like this,
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.10 \end{itemize}

? x

In Overleaf, you will see a red box at the top showing the number of errors Overleaf had to ignore to produce a result.
You should never ignore compilation errors. Output after an error is not reliable and intended only as a debugging aid1.
An itemize environment must always begin with an \item.
\begin{itemize}
  \item An item
\end{itemize}

The same is true for all other lists in LaTeX e.g. enumerate and description.
To modify the settings for the list, I recommend using enumitem. This provides a key-value syntax to customise the format and additionally lets you configure custom environment, should the need arise.
It is not entirely clear to me what you mean by 'right aligned' or 'indented'. By default, itemize indents the entire item. Since you are trying to change the default settings, you apparently want something further.
Compare the following formats:

Settings:

The first uses the default settings. All lines are indented and aligned left, with the bullet to the left of the item block on the first line.
The second uses the settings you provided. Note that these do not indent subsequent lines as much as the first line, but the lines are still indented relative to the text block.
The third is a guess as to another format you might want, which is not the default and differs from the settings you gave, but possibly matches your description. In this version, the second and subsequent lines align with the bullet point rather than the first line.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
I have right aligned the items as shown below in Latex. However, only
the first line of each item is indented and the rest follows the
original indent. How can I correct it for the entire item to be
indented.
\begin{itemize}
  \item I have right aligned the items as shown below in Latex. However, only
  the first line of each item is indented and the rest follows the
  original indent. How can I correct it for the entire item to be
  indented.
\end{itemize}
I have right aligned the items as shown below in Latex. However, only
the first line of each item is indented and the rest follows the
original indent. How can I correct it for the entire item to be
indented.
\begin{itemize}
  [itemsep=2pt,leftmargin=5pt,itemindent=20pt]
  \item I have right aligned the items as shown below in Latex. However, only
  the first line of each item is indented and the rest follows the
  original indent. How can I correct it for the entire item to be
  indented.
\end{itemize}
I have right aligned the items as shown below in Latex. However, only
the first line of each item is indented and the rest follows the
original indent. How can I correct it for the entire item to be
indented.
\begin{itemize}
  [itemsep=2pt,labelwidth=10pt,align=left,leftmargin=\parindent,labelindent=\parindent,itemindent=*]
  \item I have right aligned the items as shown below in Latex. However, only
  the first line of each item is indented and the rest follows the
  original indent. How can I correct it for the entire item to be
  indented.
\end{itemize}
I have right aligned the items as shown below in Latex. However, only
the first line of each item is indented and the rest follows the
original indent. How can I correct it for the entire item to be
indented.
\end{document}

1 Although Overleaf may give you the impression it is OK because you get a PDF, this is only because it ignores compilation errors whenever possible. That is, it tries to produce some kind of compiled document, even if a very buggy one.
